# Libre Office Calc - csv import manipulate my float

Tags: csv, libreoffice-calc

when i import following csv file:

```
test
413.298
```

it becomes in libre office calc:

```
test
413298
```

is that a bug or what is going wrong?
in the import preview it shows correctly, but after import, the comma is gone[image]

[image]

test-file: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/168374/test.csv

Comment: Which language settings are you using? You example doesn't show a comma but a point, which may be relevant depending on your language settings, especially regarding the decimal separator. You may enable detecting of numbers by using the "`Detect special numbers`" option in the import wizard.

Comment: oh sorry, i use utf-8 and ; as separator

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your case, the **language setting in the CSV import dialogue is crucial**.

Since you've selected german language, LO expects a comma (`,`) as decimal separator. With german localization, a dot (`.`) just separates thousands: `100.000,50`. Thus, `413298` is the default integer representation for `413.298`.

If LO should treat the dot in `413.298` as decimal separator, you'll have to change the language to `English (US)` in the CSV import dialog. Now, LO will display the value as `413,298`, automatically adapting the decimal separator to the overall language settings (Menu "`Tools`" -> "`Options`" -> "`Language settings`") - assuming you're working with an overall language setting to german (as me ;-) ).